# Compact Eucledean hypersurfaces with "almost" constant H_k curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $M$ be an Eucledean $n$-dimensional compact hypersurface with constant $H_k$ curvature, where $k=1,...n$. A theorem by A.Ros tell us that so $M$ is an Eucledean sphere. Does anybody know if there are generalizations of such theorem?

In particular, I need something for Eucledean compact convex hypersurfaces that have $H_k$ curvature bounded and "almost" constant, in the sense that the measure of regions where $H_k$ is not constant is very small.

More precisely: let {$M_\epsilon$} be a family of convex compact Eucledean $n$-dimensional hypersurfaces depending by a parameter $\epsilon>0$. $M_\epsilon$ is $H_k$-constant except for a region whose measure is smaller than $\epsilon$. Furthermore we know that $H_k$ is bounded on $M_\epsilon$ uniformely respect to $\epsilon$.

Does exist some result that allows to say that when $\epsilon$ approaches to zero, then $M_\epsilon$ is "close" to a sphere?

A reference for A.Ros theorem is"Compact hypersurfaces with constant higher order mean curvatures." Rev. Mat. Iberoamericana 3 (1987), no. 3-4, 447–453.

Comment: What is $k?$ What is the ambient dimension? What is A. Ros' theorem? Please try to make the question self-contained...

Comment: H_k is the k-th elementary function of the principal curvatures.

Comment: If the hypersurface is convex, the answer is positive; see theorem 7.2.8 of Schneider "Convex bodies: The Brunn-Minkowski theory".

Comment: As it is currently formulated, the question has an easy negative answer: a smoothed out cube is far from a sphere, but can be made flat outside a set of arbitrarily small measure. I guess that what you want is an integral pinching of $H_k$ or something like that?

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I have some extra hypothesis: M is convex and H_k can't be arbitrarily big. This seems to exclude your example. I'd  like to say that if M is arbitrarily close to be H_k constant (in the sense I wrote in my question), then it's a sphere.

Comment: @MariaChiaraBertini: this extra information should be made more precise and included in the question. Otherwise it will be difficult to give a good answer.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: thank you, I modified my question.

Comment: @flowguy: thank you very much. It seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

One can construct surfaces with mean curvature uniformly close to $1$, but look like collections of almost-touching spheres connected by perturbed catenoidal necks. The work of Ciraolo-Maggi ([here](http://cvgmt.sns.it/paper/2660/%22Maggi_Ciraolo%22)) shows a certain stability result for these configurations. See the references therein for the constructions of these surfaces, and a discussion of other results (e.g. Hausdorff closeness to a single sphere with more hypotheses, like convexity or smallness of oscillation of mean curvature relative to the largest principal curvature).